# Assembler: Understanding how to calculate an average

Tags: assembly, x86

The comment of the Code above says: Calculation of N numbers from Memory adress A. The Code is only for educational purpose...

I'm trying to understand how the calculation of an average is working in assembler. The Code comments are written by me. If I'm understanding something wrong pls add it to your answer. The part which I'm not understanding is especially `ADD EBX,4`.

The purpose of this Code is to get the average of all the numbers in the memory address `A`. Please read the comments carefully.

```
MOV ECX, [N]      ;Loading count of numbers in ECX
JZ done           ; If the count of numbers is 0 go to done
MOV EBX, [A]      ; Load all the numbers which are in memory space [A] in EBX
MOV EAX,0         ; EAX will be the result
Loop: ADD EAX, [EBX] ;Add first number of EBX to EAX?
ADD EBX, 4           ;What is this doing and how does it work, why would you add the number 4?
DEC ECX              ;Numbers to add - 1
JNZ Loop             ;Jump if not zero, and repeat the loop
DIV [N]              ;Divide the result of the calculation
Done: ;value of average in EAX
```

The questions are in the Code comments. 
Provide me with  Information what `[A]`and `[N]` is and how they are working and especially what `ADD EBX,4` is doing? Thanks in regard.

Comment: 8086/8088 don't have 32-bit registers like _ECX_,_EBX_,_EAX_. Those 16-bit processors support the 16-bit versions _CX_, _AX_, _BX_ (and the high/low byte portions).

Comment: Assuming this is actually 386 code then `ADD EBX,4` is to traverse an array of DWORD (32-bit values). A DWORD is 32-bits wide (4-bytes). So to go from one DWORD to the next you have to add 4 to the addres in _EBX_ upon each iteration. `ADD EAX, [EBX]` takes the DWORD value at the memory address pointed to by _EBX_ and adds it to the value in _EAX_, storing the result of the add in _EAX_

Comment: @MichaelPetch Good to know, The Code is only for educational purpose. I don't know for which processor it is working, not even if it is working on one Kind processor :(

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks, now I'm understanding what it is doing. Google didn't help me - I didn't know what to search for.

Comment: The code seems to make the assumption that the number of elements in the array of DWORDS is passed in some 32-bit value stored in a memory location labeled `N`. It seems to also assume that there is a 32-bit memory address stored **at** label `A` that points to an array of DWORDs.

Comment: What you need to do is look at an instruction set reference and/or review the text book and course material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the definition of the variables "N" and "A", they look like this:

```
.data
  N     dd 5
  ARRAY dd 1,2,3,4,5
  A     dd ?
```

We now "N" is type "dd" because in your code "N" is been assigned to register "ECX", which size is 32 bit :

```
MOV ECX, [N]      ;Loading count of numbers in ECX
```

"A" is a pointer to an array of numbers (as @MichaelPetch pointed out), because register "EBX" is set to "[A]" and its value is added to EAX on each loop:

```
mov [A], offset ARRAY      ;A IS THE ADDRES OF THE ARRAY OF NUMBERS.
MOV EBX, [A]               ;IN IDEAL MODE VARIABLES VALUE IS ACCESSED WITH BRACKETS.
...
Loop: ADD EAX, [EBX] ;Add first number of EBX to EAX?
```

By the way, the label "Loop:" might be a problem, because that's the name of a instruction, let's change the name by "Loopy:" :

```
Loopy: ADD EAX, [EBX] ;Add first number of EBX to EAX?
...
JNZ Loopy             ;Jump if not zero, and repeat the loop
```

Register "EBX" works as a pointer to the array of numbers "ARRAY":

```
mov [A], offset ARRAY  ;A IS THE ADDRES OF THE ARRAY OF NUMBERS.
MOV EBX, [A]           ; Load all the numbers which are in memory space [A] in EBX
```

This pointer must be moved forward, the first time it points to "1" (the first number in the array "ARRAY" pointed by "A"), to make it point to the rest of numbers, we have to add "4" to it on each loop, because the array "ARRAY" (pointed by "A") is type "dd", which means each element's size is 4 bytes :

```
ADD EBX, 4           ;What is this doing and how does it work, why would you add the number 4?
```

Finally, the division by "[N]" :

```
DIV [N]              ;Divide the result of the calculation
```

The "DIV" instruction, when the value is "dd" uses "EDX" register also, so it would be a good idead to clear "EDX" to avoid a wrong result :

```
MOV EDX, 0
DIV [N]              ;Divide the result of the calculation
```

Now that "EDX" is 0, the division will divide "EAX" only, and get the average.

Comment: I think `MOV EBX, [A]` suggests that A is a pointer to an array of DWORDS? . If `A` was that actual pointer to array I'd expect the instruction to be `LEA EBX, [A]`?

Comment: With your edit, couldn't you just put ARRAY's address into variable A at compile time. Something like `A dd ARRAY`? It is unclear whether this is 16-bit code using 32-bit registers (pointers being 16-bit WORDS) or this is 32-bit code with 32-bit addresses. If it is 32-bit code A should be a `DD` instead of `DW`?

Comment: Thanks again, @MichaelPetch.

Answer (score 2):

```
MOV ECX, [N]      ;Loading count of numbers in ECX
JZ done           ; If the count of numbers is 0 go to done
```

The second comment is wrong. The `mov` will not change ZF, so the conditional jump will happen upon value of ZF from caller.

To have a code working as the comments suggest, you would have to test the fetched value like this:

```
MOV ECX, [N]      ;Loading count of numbers in ECX
TEST ecx,ecx      ; do virtual "AND ecx,ecx" and set only flags
JZ done           ; If the count of numbers is 0 go to done
```

Or `CMP ecx,0`, or the `JZ` can be replaced by `JECXZ` without setting ZF. (or probably million other cryptic ways, how to set some flag when ecx is zero, without changing it content... did anyone mention `OR ecx,ecx` ...)

Comment: Please don't mention `or ecx,ecx`, that's stupid because it can't macro-fuse with a conditional branch.  And adds a cycle of latency before ecx can be used by the next instruction.  Yes, there are limitless ways to do it, but `test/jz` is the only good one :P.  Or `jecxz` isn't terrible on some CPUs.